# How to Find the Average/Day/employee in MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I've joined two tables.

I need the avg of the max number (or count) from the set_num per day per employee and display their supervisor as well. What i have so far....

```
SELECT e.supervisor, COUNT(s.set_num), e.employee
FROM sarav.employees e 
JOIN sarav.set_count s 
ON e.lis_login = s.login
group by e.employee 
order by e.supervisor;
```

This code gave me the supervisor's name, the count of their numbers total for the year, and the employee name. What I would like better is the average of their count per day per employee.

Here is some sample data that i would be working with (wink)

Employee    supervisor  login   date_set    set_num

Sam Smith   John Smith  ssmith  22-01-10    1

Sam Smith   John Smith  ssmith  22-01-10    2

Sam Smith   John Smith  ssmith  22-01-10    3

Sam Smith   John Smith  ssmith  22-01-10    4

Sam Smith   John Smith  ssmith  22-01-10    5

Sam Smith   John Smith  ssmith  22-01-10    6

Sam Smith   John Smith  ssmith  22-01-10    7

Sam Smith   John Smith  ssmith  22-01-10    8

Sam Smith   John Smith  ssmith  22-01-11    1

Sam Smith   John Smith  ssmith  22-01-11    2

Sam Smith   John Smith  ssmith  22-01-11    3

Sam Smith   John Smith  ssmith  22-01-11    4

Jane John   john smith  jjohn   22-05-08    1

Jane John   john smith  jjohn   22-05-08    2

Jane John   john smith  jjohn   22-05-08    3

Jane John   john smith  jjohn   22-05-08    4

Jane John   john smith  jjohn   22-05-08    5

Jane John   john smith  jjohn   22-05-08    6

Jane John   john smith  jjohn   22-05-08    7

Jane John   john smith  jjohn   22-05-09    1

Jane John   john smith  jjohn   22-05-09    2

Jane John   john smith  jjohn   22-05-09    3

Jane John   john smith  jjohn   22-05-09    4

Jane John   john smith  jjohn   22-05-09    5

Amy Joe     Scar Johan  ajoe    22-05-11    1

Amy Joe     Scar Johan  ajoe    22-05-11    2

Amy Joe     Scar Johan  ajoe    22-05-11    3

Amy Joe     Scar Johan  ajoe    22-05-14    1

Amy Joe     Scar Johan  ajoe    22-05-14    2

Amy Joe     Scar Johan  ajoe    22-05-14    3

Amy Joe     Scar Johan  ajoe    22-05-14    4

Result I'm trying to obtain:

Employee  Supervisor Login Avg_Set_Num_Day

Sam Smith John Smith ssmith   8.3

Jane John John Smith jjohn    5.2

Amy Joe   Scar Johan ajoe     6.5

Comment: What should "then I need" mean? Should "then" mean another column in your result or should it mean a new query with an own result? Please show some sample data and the expected result(s) of your query/queries. Read here how and why to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Also make sure to only ask one question. Reading your description I'm skeptical if this is the case.

Comment: Hi. I will edit to reflect this but I need all of this in the final result. I need to take the average of the max set_num per day per employee with their supervisor listed in the final result as well. I will make up some sample data also and post here

Comment: Help us help you - share some sample data and the result you're trying to get for it

Comment: just shared some sample data @Mureinik